# How can I add multiple variables to a label text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm really new to python so I'd really appreiciate some help.
This is a example of what I mean:

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
a='I'
b='like'
c='programming'
lbl=Label(root,text=a'.',b'.',c,'.')
lbl.pack()

mainloop()
```

This is what I am trying to output:

```
I.like.programming.
```

Comment: f-strings in Python3.6+: `text=f'{a}.{b}.{c}.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the strings. Convert variable to strings if they are not strings and then add them.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
a='I'
b='like'
c='programming'
lbl=Label(root,text=a+'.'+b+'.'+c+'.')
lbl.pack()

mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]